# How to use nested list comprehensions in python?

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like below. This list stores errors occurred for each name along with information regarding if this was directly or indirectly queried.

```
errors=[
    {
        'name': 'name-1',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'unknown error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-2',
        'type':'indirect_queried',
        'error': 'some denied error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-3',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'some not found error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-4',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'some denied error'
    },

]
```

Then, from a given list of names, I have to segregate names based upon errors occurred if any for that name.

So for below list of names,

```
names=['name-1','name-2','name-3']
```

the output should like below. Also, I am just interested in `direct_queried` error types.

```
success=[] // as error occurred for each name in the names list

unauthorized=['name-4'] // as error message contains denied and the error type is direct queried.

not_found=['name-3'] // as error message contains not found and the error type is direct queried.

unknown=['name-1'] // as error is direct queried and error is not denied or not found.

// 'name-2' is excluded as it's indirectly queried error.
```

I am trying to use a find a way to do this in a one liner list-comprehension way like below. [Referring](https://builtin.com/data-science/nested-list-comprehension-python)

```
success=[name for name in names if ....(check each item in errors list and see if this name matches doesn't match any name in errors list  whose type is direct_queried.)]

unauthorized=[name for name in names if ....(check each item in errors list and see if this name matches any name in errors list  whose type is direct_queried and error contains denied word.)]

not_found=[name for name in names if ....(check each item in errors list and see if this name matches any name in errors list  whose type is direct_queried and error contains not found.)]

unknown=[name for name in names if ....(check each item in errors list and see if this name matches any name in errors list  whose type is direct_queried and error doesn't contain denied or not found word.)]
```

Can someone please guide me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `errors`, not `names`, in your list comprehension:

```py
unauthorized = [
    error["name"] for error in errors
    if error["error"] == "unauthorized"
]
```

Then you can filter out the names that you want:

```py
unauthorized = [name for name in unauthorized if name in names]
```

Alternatively, you can put it into a single comprehension:

```py
unauthorized = [
    error["name"] for error in errors
    if error["error"] == "unauthorized" and error["name"] in names
]
```

Or you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and a set comprehension:

```py
names = {"name-1", "name-2", "name-3"]
unauthorized = names & {error["name"] for error in errors if error["error"] == "unauthorized"}
```

(the `&` operator represents [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)))

---

If you find that you have to repeat this kind of construct for different types of errors, you can extract it into a function:

```py
def find_errors(errors, names, error_type):
    return names & {e for e in errors if e["error"] == error_type}

names = {"name-1", "name-2", "name-3", "name-4"}
unauthorized = find_errors(errors, names, "unauthorized")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
success = [
    item for item in errors
    if item["name"] not in names and item["type"] == "direct_queried"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

here, hope this helps :

```
errors=[
    {
        'name': 'name-1',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'unknown error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-2',
        'type':'indirect_queried',
        'error': 'some denied error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-3',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'some not found error'
    },
    {
        'name': 'name-4',
        'type':'direct_queried',
        'error': 'some denied error'
    },
]
names = names=['name-1','name-2','name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5']

success = [name for name in names if name not in [error['name'] for error in errors]]
unknown = [error['name'] for error in errors if 'unknown' in error['error'].lower()]
not_found = [error['name'] for error in errors if 'not found' in error['error'].lower()]
unauthorized = [error['name'] for error in errors if 'denied' in error['error'].lower()]

print("success: ", success)
print("Unknown: ", unknown)
print("not_found: ", not_found)
print("unauthorized: ", unauthorized)
```

output:

```
success:  ['name-5']
Unknown:  ['name-1']
not_found:  ['name-3']
unauthorized:  ['name-2', 'name-4']
```